# Travel Insurance for when you are not returning to your country of departure

Tags: insurance

I'm seeking some advice on travel insurance. I'm a South African citizen currently residing in Thailand. I'm leaving Thailand to go back to South Africa but will visit some countries in Europe on my way back. In order to get a Schengen visa I need travel insurance. The Thai insurance companies I've contacted can only sell me the insurance if I return to Thailand and the South African companies can only sell it to me if I depart from South Africa. Lonely planet has a travel insurance service called World Nomads. It looks as if they'll be able to sell me the insurance for $213/ 2 months. Is that a good price or does anyone know of something better? Thanks

Comment: I just saw some related posts. Thanks, I got enough info from that

Comment: could you perhaps answer your question then, so that others who are in the same situation in the future can benefit?

Comment: In the FWIW department World Nomads is not part of Lonely Planet, only a recommended insurance supplier.

Answer (score 3):

I have used travel health insurance from [CareMed](https://www.work-and-travel-insurance.com/) who, like World Nomads, provides post-departure policies if your departure date was less than three months ago. Having experienced both CareMed and World Nomads (and have submitted claims to both) I can not recommend World Nomads since they revealed some hidden restrictions and blocked my claim, while I had a positive experience using CareMed.

(And not related, but I would like to recommend [GeoBlue](https://geobluetravelinsurance.com/) for travel health insurance if you are a US citizen and can purchase it before you depart on your trip. They are awesome.)