# Travel Insurance Help (little complicated)

Tags: insurance

I am a Canadian/Polish citizen. I am currently living in Germany as a student - and have been for the past 2 years. My studies end at the end of October, and I am planning to go to Tanzania directly from Germany for a holiday. After this I will be returning to Canada (flight: TANZANIA-QTAR-FRANKFURT-VANCOUVER).

I require travel insurance for my trip to Tanzania. I have already called my Credit Card company, and they informed me that I am only covered for 21 days which starts when I leave my province. In other words, no good there (since I've been in Germany for 2 years).

I am quite confused what insurance I should get, and even more confused to what I should put for the country I reside in on the online forms.

I have checked out: https://www.worldnomads.com, and they define this as "The country where you can be repatriated to in a medical emergency under this insurance where, if necessary, you can receive on-going medical care after this insurance ends." -- I guess this is Canada? I still have medical coverage there - being a citizen and all.

I am seeking some advice, because I want some peace of mind that if something does happen (knock on wood) I am covered. I know these insurance companies are pretty nasty sometimes. I don't want them to be - oh but you haven't been in Canada in 2 years... blah blah... or something.

Also, what insurance companies would you recommend for my situation? Is worldnomads.com any good?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does this Q&A help? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43142/travel-insurance-for-when-you-are-not-returning-to-your-country-of-departure?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travel Insurance for when you are not returning to your country of departure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43142/travel-insurance-for-when-you-are-not-returning-to-your-country-of-departure)